# Nodejs Passing argument to fork object

Tags: node.js, memory, arguments, fork

How to send "--max_old_space_size=1024" to child process fork?
I tried to send this argument as args , argv
Note that because I need communication channel, I could not use exec or spawn.
So basically I want run my child process

```
require('child_process').fork('myfile.js');
```

as

```
node --max_old_space_size=1024 myfile.js
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for [the `execArgv` property of `fork`'s options](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options):

```js
require('child_process').fork('myfile.js', {
  execArgv: ['--max_old_space_size=1024']
});
```

Then in `myfile.js` you can check it's been considered through [`process.execArgv`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_execargv):

```js
console.log(process.execArgv);
```

Which should output the same as if you directly call:

```js
node --max_old_space_size=1024 myfile.js
```

This differentiates these 2 types of arguments: `node <node's args> file.js <file's args>`

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you know what is the best way of sending large data to the fork? currently I am sending via env object but it looks it is too big and it does not let the value reach to the fork.

Comment: Your question states: _"Note that because I need communication channel, I could not use exec or spawn."_ The documentation for `fork` that I linked above states: _"The returned ChildProcess will have an additional communication channel built-in that allows messages to be passed back and forth between the parent and child. See [`subprocess.send()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback) for details."_ I thought that's what you were using - anyway probably what you want to use.